# How to get Python support in Vim (not gVim) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, vim

I read that Vim and gVim in the same installation are supposed to be identical, excluding the graphical interface obviously. However I was trying to figure out why some plugins wouldn't load into Vim (not gVim). I was following a tutorial that mentioned that Window's Vim already has Python support built in. After more checking I learned about `:version` and tried it in both Vim and gVim of the same installation.

gVim:

```
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 12 2019 13:30:17)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Compiled by mool@tororo
Huge version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl                +cindent            +cursorshape        -farsi              +jumplist           +mksession          +path_extra         +rightleft          +tag_binary         +title              +wildignore
+arabic             +clientserver       +dialog_con_gui     +file_in_path       +keymap             +modify_fname       +perl/dyn           +ruby/dyn           -tag_old_static     +toolbar            +wildmenu
+autocmd            +clipboard          +diff               +find_in_path       +lambda             +mouse              +persistent_undo    +scrollbind         -tag_any_white      +user_commands      +windows
+autochdir          +cmdline_compl      +digraphs           +float              +langmap            +mouseshape         +popupwin           +signs              +tcl/dyn            +vartabs            +writebackup
+autoservername     +cmdline_hist       +directx            +folding            +libcall            +multi_byte_ime/dyn -postscript         +smartindent        -termguicolors      +vertsplit          -xfontset
+balloon_eval       +cmdline_info       -dnd                -footer             +linebreak          +multi_lang         +printer            +sound              +terminal           +virtualedit        -xim
-balloon_eval_term  +comments           -ebcdic             +gettext/dyn        +lispindent         +mzscheme/dyn       +profile            +spell              -termresponse       +visual             +xpm_w32
+browse             +conceal            +emacs_tags         -hangul_input       +listcmds           +netbeans_intg      +python/dyn         +startuptime        +textobjects        +visualextra        -xterm_save
++builtin_terms     +cryptv             +eval               +iconv/dyn          +localmap           +num64              +python3/dyn        +statusline         +textprop           +viminfo
+byte_offset        +cscope             +ex_extra           +insert_expand      +lua/dyn            +ole                +quickfix           -sun_workshop       -tgetent            +vreplace
+channel            +cursorbind         +extra_search       +job                +menu               +packages           +reltime            +syntax             +timers             -vtp
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -
DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_MSWIN -DFEAT_DIRECTX -DDYNAMIC_DIRECTX -DFEAT_DIRECTX_COLOR_EMOJI -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl86t.dll\"
 -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.6\" -DFEAT_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA_DLL=\"lua53.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python36.dll\" -DFEAT_MZSCH
EME -I "E:\Racket\include" -DMZ_PRECISE_GC -DDYNAMIC_MZSCHEME -DDYNAMIC_MZSCH_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_MZGC_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_P
ERL_DLL=\"perl524.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby240.dll\" -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjGXOULYHTRZi386/ /Zi
Linking: link  /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.
lib netapi32.lib  /machine:i386  libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib user32.lib  /nodefaultlib:lua53.lib  /STACK:8388608  /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python36.lib   "E:\ActiveTcl\lib\tclstub86.lib" winmm.lib WSock32.lib xpm\x86\lib-vc14
\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug
```

Vim:

```
:version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Dec 12 2019 13:19:27)                                                                                                                                                                              
MS-Windows 32-bit console version                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Compiled by mool@tororo                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):                                                                                                                                                                                    
+acl               +channel           +cscope            +ex_extra          +iconv/dyn         +listcmds          -mzscheme          +profile           +sound             +termguicolors     +vartabs           +windows                       
+arabic            +cindent           +cursorbind        +extra_search      +insert_expand     +localmap          -netbeans_intg     -python            +spell             +terminal          +vertsplit         +writebackup                   
+autocmd           +clientserver      +cursorshape       -farsi             +job               -lua               +num64             -python3           +startuptime       -termresponse      +virtualedit       -xfontset                      
+autochdir         +clipboard         +dialog_con        +file_in_path      +jumplist          +menu              +packages          +quickfix          +statusline        +textobjects       +visual            -xim                           
+autoservername    +cmdline_compl     +diff              +find_in_path      +keymap            +mksession         +path_extra        +reltime           -sun_workshop      +textprop          +visualextra       -xpm_w32                       
-balloon_eval      +cmdline_hist      +digraphs          +float             +lambda            +modify_fname      -perl              +rightleft         +syntax            -tgetent           +viminfo           -xterm_save                    
+balloon_eval_term +cmdline_info      -dnd               +folding           +langmap           +mouse             +persistent_undo   -ruby              +tag_binary        +timers            +vreplace                                         
-browse            +comments          -ebcdic            -footer            +libcall           -mouseshape        +popupwin          +scrollbind        -tag_old_static    +title             +vtp                                              
++builtin_terms    +conceal           +emacs_tags        +gettext/dyn       +linebreak         +multi_byte        -postscript        +signs             -tag_any_white     -toolbar           +wildignore                                       
+byte_offset       +cryptv            +eval              -hangul_input      +lispindent        +multi_lang        +printer           +smartindent       -tcl               +user_commands     +wildmenu                                         
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"                                                                                                                                                                                                              
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"                                                                                                                                                                                                
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_SOUND  -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL      -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG /arch:IA32 /Zl /MT -DDYNAMIC_
ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjCi386/ /Zi                                                                                                                                                                                          
Linking:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
link  /nologo /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386   libcmt.lib  user32.lib          winmm.lib WSock32.lib  /PDB:vim.pdb -debug
```

From the `:version` details I see that gVim has the expected

```
+python/dyn +python3/dyn
```

entries but Vim instead has

```
-python -python3
```

Was I mistaken in thinking that these two should be identical in their build configuration? Do I need to rebuild vi from scratch to get the command line version of Vim to include Python support? or is there some simpler method? Or maybe should I report this discrepancy as a bug somewhere?

[EDIT]

Removed image of `:version` outputs and pasted their text directly into this post. Also switched to version 8.2 (was 8.1).

Comment: I've seen this issue fixed by installing/reinstalling Python, then rebooting. Note that whatever version of Vim you use (32-bit or 64-bit), you must also have the same type of Python installation for Vim to load the libraries

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The image is intended to show what interface I'm using to make my deductions and provide that context in case more knowledgeable users might see something wrong in the ways that I have arrived at my conclusions. I stand by my post if you were to disclude the image, and if you are bothered by it, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @Das_Geek restarted and I'm still seeing vim with `-python` and `-python3`

Comment: @BarakGall the image is unnecessary and hard to read on mobile. Copy/pasting the version info is not hard and makes the *text* far more readable and workable. I stand by my comment.

Comment: Can't add an answer, but for anyone else this happens to, it turns out that the vim installer build used for windows has a misconfiguration between the two separate builds used for gVim and vim. I'm trying to follow up on this here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5355

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATE]

It turns out that vim-win32-installer repo has python capabilities in both gvim and vim. The releases can be found here: https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer/releases

[Original Answer]

It turns out that the vim installer build used for windows has a misconfiguration between the two separate builds used for gVim and vim. I tried to follow up on this here: github.com/vim/vim/issues/5355

At the present time the consensus seems to lean towards this not being a big enough issue and people can just build vim manually if they want another feature-set. While I disagree with this in general, I can definitely understand this is not a priority and hope that the powers that be get the two builds in sync in the future. Please contribute your own thoughts to that task.